# Java decrypting RSA encrypted data ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: too much data for RSA block

Tags: java, android, cryptography, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm encrypting some data on a Phoenix webserver:

```
private_key = ExPublicKey.load!("private.pem")
token = %{username: user.username, mobile_phone: user.mobile_phone, email: user.email}
payload = Poison.encode!(token)
{:ok, signature} = ExPublicKey.encrypt_private(payload, private_key)
```

And decrypting it on the Java (actually Android) client as follows:

```
try {
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(Constants.RSA_PUBLIC_KEY.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    X509EncodedKeySpec encodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(encodedKeySpec) ;
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA") ;
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey) ;
    //
    Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, jwt) ; // received token
    String payload = new String(Base64.decode(jwt, Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8") ; // java does UTF16, elixir does UTF8
    Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, payload) ; // base64 decoded token
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(payload.getBytes("UTF-8")) ; // decrypt
    String token = new String(Base64.decode(cipherText, Base64.URL_SAFE), "UTF-8") ; // cipher text is urlencoded
    Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, token) ;
    return null ;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

There are no exceptions on the Phoenix side but trying to decrypt the token on java results in the exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: too much data for RSA block
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:459)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1502
```

If the input is too large for the RSA modulus it should have resulted in error on the webserver. So I'm wondering what is actually wrong.

UPDATE: seems like there was an issue with library. The output produced by signing the SHA256 digest of some data returns 344 bytes, whereas its supposed to be 256 bytes for the key length used. Reverted to using Erlang's `public_key` module and it works fine now.

Comment: 1. What is the data sie and the key size? The data length must be less than the key size. 2. Unless you ereally ned asymmetric encryption (RSA) use AES which can handle any size of data you need.

Comment: It seems to me that you're not encrypting anything. "Encrypting" with the private key is called *signing* and "decrypting" with the public key and comparing the result is called *verifying*. What is it that you want to achieve? Usually, a hash is signed and not actual data.

Comment: I was initially planning to use RSA keys for encryption (rather than signing) so as to avoid the hassle of managing AES keys. But the issue here is below that. Even when only applying the 2048 bit private key to a SHA256 hash of data, the Java side still fails with the same exception.

Comment: @Parsoa Without some example values this is plain guessing.

Comment: @Parsoa, are you trying to implement Json Web Tokens?

Comment: @pedrofb More or less. I don't really like the way the `joken` library handles stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Is not clear the real purpose and that makes things difficult, but if you are trying to issue JSON Web Tokens, as it seems, your implementation is completely wrong

- JWT is digitally signed, not encrypted
- encrypt with private key != Digital signature
- you are "decrypting" the entire token instead of verifying the signature, which should be the last part of a JSON Web Token like this `hhhh.pppp.ssss`.

@zaph described the error, but it would not occur if you use digital signature. It is not possible to fix your code so consider to re-implement it

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wasn't initially planning on implementing JWT but rather rolling out a custom protocol more suited to the application requirements and was simply stuck at getting the RSA part to work. The error as mentioned by @zaph seems to have been caused by weird behavior (or maybe bad usage) of the library and was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Signing is not the same as encrypting using a private key. Although both would be using modular exponentiation with the private exponent signing and encryption use different padding methods. More information [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997/1172). You should basically not see hashing and signing as separate operations: the hashing is *part of* the signature generation and verification.

The reason why your code failed is however different: the signature is likely encoded using base64. Base64 will generate an output size of [`ceiling(256/3)×4`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ceil(256+%2F+3)+*+4). This of course equals 344 characters / bytes. So you first would have to decode the result before decrypting it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to use hybrid encryption. Namely, this involves using RSA to asymmetrically encrypt a symmetric key.

Randomly generate a symmetric encryption (say AES) key and encrypt the plaintext message with it. Then, encrypt the symmetric key with RSA. Transmit both the symmetrically encrypted text as well as the asymmetrically encrypted symmetric key.

The receiver can then decrypt the RSA block, which will yield the symmetric key, allowing the symmetrically encrypted text to be decrypted.

This can be shown more formally as the following. Let MM be the plaintext, KAESKAES be the randomly chosen AES key, and KPuKPu be the receiver's public RSA key you already have.

```
C1=EAES(M,KAES)
C1=EAES(M,KAES)
C2=ERSA(KAES,KPu)
C2=ERSA(KAES,KPu)
Then, send both C1C1 and C2C2.
```

Let KPrKPr be the receiver's private RSA key. The receiver can then recover MM as

```
KAES=DRSA(C2,KPr)
KAES=DRSA(C2,KPr)
M=DAES(C1,KAES)
M=DAES(C1,KAES)
```

(To allow streaming decryption or large messages, you would usually send C2C2 first and then (the much larger) C1C1.)

Comment: Normally, I would upvote such an answer, but it seems that OP doesn't want or need hybrid encryption. Instead it seems to me that they want to sign and verify stuff.